# Deleting documents not belonging to an index

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have been evaluating elasticsearch 5.1.1. My data upload happens via NEST. I have used two different types and different index names while testing. Now that I have a better understanding of the API, I have settled on a type. I deleted all the indices and created a new one.

My documents have their own ID and I have fluent code as follows

```
config.InferMappingFor<SearchFriendlyIssue>(ib => ib.IdProperty(p => p.Id));
```

When I upload documents, the API comes back as "Updated". This is strange, since I just created a new index. What is worse, my new index only contains one document. What I expected is to have a Created response. The code to add data is as per the API documentation

```
var searchObject = new SearchFriendlyIssue(issue);
var response = Client.Index(searchObject, idx => idx.Index(Index));
Console.WriteLine(response.Result.ToString());
```

I think I am missing something around how types and indices interact. How do I get rid of my unreachable documents? Rather more specifically how do I get them into my index so they can be deleted or dealt with?

Comment: When your POCO contains an `Id` property (or you explicitly tell the client which property should be used as the Id), the value for this property will be used to set the `_id` metadata for the document in Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the assumption I had unreachable documents was wrong. Instead, the declaration for the ID property wasn't working, and I was overwriting the same document over and over again. My bad!